# Cant generate image for required email

Tags: php

I want to write a program where I will insert a particular id through form in database and the corresponding email will be displayed in image in jpeg format.

But I am not getting the required email instead I am getting image with this text "No email upload".

I have 3 files in one folder

```
index.php,
connect_sql.php,
generate_image.php
```

Below is code in `index.php`

```
<?php
   require 'connect_sql.php';
   if(isset($_GET['id'])){
       $id = $_GET['id'];
       if(!empty($id)){
           global $conn;
           $escaped_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$id);
           $query = "SELECT username,email FROM user_table WHERE id = ".$escaped_id;
           $query_run = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
           $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($query_run);
           if($num_rows == 1){
               while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_run)){
                   $fetched_email = $row['email'];
                   $fetched_name = $row['username'];
                   echo $fetched_name." your email is ";
                   echo "<img src='generate_image.php' />";
               }   
           }else{
               echo "Id not found.";
           }
       }else{
           echo "Please enter id.";
       }
   }

?>
<form action="index.php" method="get">
   <p>
      Id<br />
      <input type="text" name="id" />
   </p>
   <p>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
   </p>
</form>
```

Below is code in `connect_sql.php`

```
<?php
   $hostname = "localhost";
   $username = "root";
   $password = "";
   $db_name = "php_thenewboston";
   $conn = mysqli_connect($hostname,$username,$password);
   $conn_db = mysqli_select_db($conn,$db_name);
   if(!$conn || !$conn_db){
       die("Connection unsuccessful.");
   }
?>
```

Below is code in `generate_image.php`

```
<?php
   header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
   if(!empty($fetched_email)){
       $email = $fetched_email;
   }else{
       $email = "No email uploaded.";
   }

   $email_length = strlen($email);
   $font_size = 16;
   $imageHeight = ImageFontHeight($font_size);
   $image_width = $imageHeight * $email_length;
   $image = imagecreate($image_width,$imageHeight);
   imagecolorallocate($image,255,255,255);
   $font_color = imagecolorallocate($image,0,0,0);
   imagestring($image, $font_size, 0, 0, $email, $font_color);
   imagejpeg($image);
?>
```

I am unable to catch my error.

I am a beginner in php.

Please comment below for any query.